# Replacing empty value with "None" in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a **Python** dictionary that I generated from an arcgis shapefile.  The dictionary has key = FID (point ID) : value = either nothing or "HH".  The dictionary looks like this:

```
Cluster_dict = {0: [u' '], 1: [u'HH'], 2: [u'HH'], 3: [u' '], 4: [u' '], 5: [u' '], 6: [u' '], 7: [u' '], 8: [u' '], 9: [u' '], 10: [u' '], 11: [u'HH'], 12: [u'HH'], 13: [u'HH'], 14: [u'HH'], 15: [u' '], 16: [u' '], 17: [u' '], 18: [u' '], 19: [u' '], 20: [u' '], 21: [u' '], 22: [u' '], 23: [u'HH'], 24: [u'HH'], 25: [u' '], 26: [u' '], 27: [u' '], 28: [u' ']....}
```

The extra characters of the value [u' '] and [u'HH'] show up after I created the dictionary from the arcgis shapefile with the following code:

```
arcpy.ClustersOutliers_stats('input_file', "GRID_CODE", 'output_file',  "INVERSE_DISTANCE", "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE", "NONE", "", "")
Cluster_dict = {}
sc = arcpy.SearchCursor('output_file')
for row in sc:
    Cluster_dict[row.FID] = [row.COType]

print Cluster_dict
```

I'm trying to use this dictionary to append to a nested list of each point's 8 (or less) neighbors using the following code:

```
clusterList = []
for clist in Neighbors_List:
    row = []
    for ccode in clist:
        row.append(Cluster_dict[ccode])
    clusterList.append(row)
 print clusterList
```

But when it gets to row.append(Cluster_dict[ccode]), I get a **key error '0'**.  I'm thinking this is because there is no value for key 0, but I'm not sure about this.  When I used the following code to replace all the [u' '] with "None", the dictionary doesn't replace the empty values.  I'm using the following code to try and replace [u' '].

```
for k, v in Cluster_dict.iteritems():
    if v is [u' ']:       #I've also tried '[u' ']'
        Cluster_dict[k] = 'None'

print Cluster_dict
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Would it be easier to strip [u' '] out of all the values in the dictionary?  If so, can someone show me how to strip unwanted characters out of a dictionary?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Are you certain @FelixKling?  I seem to get the opposite behavior in my terminal - see my answer.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Ui... I must be wrong. Interesting, I thought `==` only gives only `true` for tuples because they are immutable, but not lists. I'm too much influenced by JavaScript apparently ;) Thanks! (will delete my comment).

Comment: About your `key error '0'`, make sure that `ccode` is a number, since from what you report it seems a string. To get an integer from a string containing the number, you would write `row.append(Cluster_dict[int(ccode)])`.

Comment: So I can't append strings from a dictionary to a nested list if the string is the value of a dictionary?

Comment: @Linda you can't index by string keys a dictionary that has integer keys only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do what you want, use `==` instead.

Also, `dict.get()`

Also, *'0'* does **not** equal *0*

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop looks good, you probably want to use `==` instead of `is` to get it working.  In Python the `is` operator compares two objects' identities.

I do seem to be able to compare lists, contrary to one of the comments:

```
>>> a = [u' ']
>>> a is [u' ']
False
>>> a == [u' ']
True
```

Comment: `>>> d={'s':[u' ']}
>>> d['s'] is [u' ']
False
>>> `

Comment: sorry thought your second one was `True`

Answer (score 2):

Other people have told you what's wrong with using `is` when you mean `==`, but you can skip that whole loop by adding some code earlier:

```
for row in sc:
    Cluster_dict[row.FID] = [row.COType] if row.COType != u' ' else None
```

Comment: Yes, that's good.  I would definitely do this if not for the [u'HH'] result when creating the dictionary from shapefile.  I'm thinking the extra characters tag along because of arcgis and mean nothing, but I still want to get rid of them and just have 'HH'.  Thanks for this suggestion though...I will use it later.